# how to convert list to array

Tags: c#, arrays, list

the problem is that the list is type of one of my class so i cant simply do to array..
this is my code:

```
public List<PhoneBookCore> elements = new List<PhoneBookCore>();
```

this is the class:

```
{
abstract class PhoneBookCore
{
    protected string _group;


    public PhoneBookCore(string group)
    {
        this._group = group;
    }

    public abstract void Add(PhoneBookCore d);
    public abstract void Remove(PhoneBookCore d);
    public abstract void Display(int indent);
}
```

}

thanks

Comment: Just loop through the contents of the List and place it into an Array. Of course I see neither a List or an Array. Why exactly do you want to do this?  I see nothing wrong with `elements`

Comment: What do you mean by `i cant simply do to array`? LINQ is not available or what?

Comment: I don't understand the question.. is this a real question even?

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem to convert a list of any of your defined classes to an array. What error exactly do you get?

Comment: There is no reason why `public List<PhoneBookCore> elements = new List<PhoneBookCore>(); PhoneBookCore[] elementsArr = elements.ToArray();` should not work..

Comment: If PhoneBookCore is an abstract class you cannot instanciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an array from the list, you can simply use `ToArray`:

```
PhoneBookCore[] bookCores = elements.ToArray();
```

If you instead want an array of the property `_group`, hence a `string[]`:

```
string[] groups = elements.Select(pbc => pbc._group).ToArray();
```

Note that you need to add `using.System.Linq` for `Enumerable.ToArray` and that the second approach is just to demonstrate how to select a property from your class and create an array. It does yet not compile since `_group` is protected as  lazyberezovsky has mentioned.

Comment: _group is protected. and OP can't use ToArray for some reason

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: good point, mentioned that. However, it's not clear what's the actual problem. I have _"i cant simply do to array"_ understood  as "i don't know how to...".

Comment: @TimSchmelter agree, that's a very unclear question

Comment: i am trying to do "string[] groups = elements.Select(pbc => pbc._group).ToArray();" but no good :( why?

Comment: @darko: Have a look at my answer, especially the last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Linq method [`ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819.aspx)? (you have to add `using System.Linq`)

```
PhoneBookCore[] myArray = elements.ToArray();
```

Comment: what is the question actually?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`.ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) LINQ extension method:

```
List<PhoneBookCore> elements = new List<PhoneBookCore>();
PhoneBookCore[] array = elements.ToArray();
```